# Echo-ing content of MySQL column prints out 'undefined'

Tags: php, mysql

I have a strange problem which I'd never encountered before.

I have a `description` column in a mysql table named `list_items`.

In some rows, the description is empty and in some it's not. The format is mediumtext, but the same problem is there when I change it to something like VARCHAR(1000).

This is the simple query:

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from list_items where list_id='$id' order by position desc") or die(mysql_error());
while($iteminfo=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    print_r($iteminfo);
}
```

And it gives something like this:

```
Array ( 
  [id] => 85 [list_id] => 16 [position] => 4 
  [item] => How To Be Richer Smarter And Better Looking Than Your Parents 
  [voted_up] => 0 [voted_down] => 0 
  [small_image] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51tdjl56TwL._SL160_.jpg
  [large_image] => http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51tdjl56TwL.jpg 
  [asin] => 1591845440 [description] => undefined [author] => Zac Bissonnette 
  [publish_date] => 2012-04-24 [genre] => )
```

The description column is always 'undefined' regardless of whether it's empty or not. Any ideas?

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `list_items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `list_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `item` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `voted_up` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `voted_down` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `small_image` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `large_image` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `asin` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `description` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `publish_date` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `genre` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=107 ;
```

var_dump returns this:

```
array(13) { ["id"]=> string(2) "87" ["list_id"]=> string(2) "16" ["position"]=> string(1) "2" ["item"]=> string(22) "Game Of Thrones Book 1" ["voted_up"]=> string(1) "1" ["voted_down"]=> string(1) "0" ["small_image"]=> string(61) "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51VcGBtiLTL._SL160_.jpg" ["large_image"]=> string(53) "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51VcGBtiLTL.jpg" ["asin"]=> string(10) "0553386794" ["description"]=> string(0) "" ["author"]=> string(18) "George R.R. Martin" ["publish_date"]=> string(10) "2011-03-22" ["genre"]=> string(0) "" }
```

But `echo $iteminfo['description']` still gives 'undefined'.

Comment: Have you tried running the query directly (e.g., through phpMyAdmin)?

Comment: your array description value is null some time or sometime it is not set.. try to use isset..

Comment: show your table structure first

Comment: @Learner That doesn't really explain the issue.

Comment: @robert did you understand anything..

Comment: @Learner So some of the rows are empty and some are not, that was never a reason for MySQL to return 'undefined'. Especially not in the rows that are NOT empty.

Comment: You are saying that some rows have `description` empty - how could this happen as You have `description mediumtext NOT NULL`???

Comment: The default value is an empty string, why should that be a problem?!

Comment: That is not quite obvious from `CREATE TABLE` query... It would then be `description mediumtext NOT NULL DEFAULT ''`, wouldn't it?

Comment: Please, please don't be using inputs unsanitized in your SQL queries.

Comment: @damianb What are you talking about? $id is an INT, what's to sanitize?

Comment: @robert Can you run the query outside of PHP? Either via phpMyAdmin as kevinmajor1 suggested or some other application. We can then eliminate PHP or MySQL as the cause.

Comment: I tried, it returns all the rows normally...if you mean the select query?

Comment: @robert Very strange. 'undefined' is not a concept PHP understands, something is either null, false, empty but to my knowledge never 'undefined'. Can you change the `print_r` to `var_dump` and give us the output - var_dump is a little more descriptive.

Comment: Also, is there anything strange about your MySQL set up? Just to make sure its totally out of date or not-normal in some way.

Comment: @robert Is this giving an undefined value on all outputs or just the rows with `description` as ''

Comment: @Bulk I know, it's strange. var_dump added to question. Nothing strange about MySQL, in fact I could swear it worked properly just yesterday.

Comment: @thebarless All rows, regardless of whether description is empty or not.

Comment: @robert do you get the same result if you use `while($iteminfo=mysql_fetch_array($result)){`?

Comment: @thebarless Yes I do, in fact the code was originally `mysql_fetch_array`, I switched to `mysql_fetch_assoc` when the former didn't work.

Comment: @robert, I intend to look into this but only if you have not yet solved it. Let me know otherwise so I can proceed. Cheers.

Comment: @profnotime Still haven't solved it - I can't figure out what's going on for the life of me. I can give you an SQL file with the contents of the database table if it would help.

Comment: @robert, Okay paste the SQL file in http://pastebin.com/ or wherever you prefer and post the link. Thanks

Comment: Here it is, sorry for waiting: [link](http://pastebin.com/JuVNdKvP)

Comment: @robert, I have exercised your sql in my own code and I get results. I do not get the undefined result you're getting. However, I will work with your data now.

Comment: @robert, I don't know whether to start laughing at myself. Took me a little while but I found it. You are not getting any errors at all. "Undefined" is actually the content of the field "description" for those records according to the data you exported and sent to me. I will edit this comment in a sec, and give you all the "IDs" of the rogue records doing this so you can check for yourself. Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow. Well this was a huge waste of everybody's time on my part. I did look at the table in phpMyAdmin but none of the problematic entries were on the first page, and all the entries I was looking at on the example page happened to be undefined. Thanks and sorry again.

Comment: @robert, I couldn't edit the comment again, time passed by profnotime lol. The "IDs" of the rogue records doing this are as follows: **97, 96, 95, 94, 86, 85, 84** in desc order. I suppose either you or someone else filled that earlier on. Hope this helps. Any further questions, please let me know.

Comment: @profnotime Please post as answer so robert can accept it. So no one else wastes more time reading this.

Comment: @robert The probable cause for you having `undefined` saved to your table, is that there is something wrong with some javascript code you are using to POST the values to PHP. It's failing to get the proper field value, and you're posting `undefined` instead.

Comment: @profnotime if you post this as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: @robert, I have done as requested. Cheers

Comment: @robert My apologies, but look at it from everyone else's perspective - we can't see what $id is - all we see is a var inside of an SQL query and nothing above it for sanitization. I find it a better idea to warn first and assume nothing about the person's skill than to ignore it and hope that they know about query safety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@robert, I am posting as answer so you can accept it and close this.
You are not getting any errors at all. "Undefined" is actually the content of the field "description" for those records according to the data you exported and sent to me.

The "IDs" of the rogue records doing this are as follows: **97, 96, 95, 94, 86, 85, 84** in desc order. I suppose either you or someone else filled that earlier on. Also, you should look into what @bfavaretto commented above. I think it may likely be the cause.

My test source code is shown below:

```
<?php
   //@Author: ProfNoTime 062012 (Test Code - Not For Production Level Use)

   $conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

   if (!$conn) { echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error(); exit; }

   if (!mysql_select_db("test")) { echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error(); exit; }

   $id = 1;
   $sqlQuery = "select * from list_items where list_id='$id' order by position desc";
   var_dump($sqlQuery);

   $result=mysql_query($sqlQuery) or die(mysql_error());

   if (!$result) { echo "Could not successfully run query ($sqlQuery) from DB: " . mysql_error(); exit; }
   else{
      if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
         echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting...bye!"; exit;
      }
   else{
         while($iteminfo=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
           print_r($iteminfo);
           var_dump($iteminfo);
         }
      }
    }

   mysql_free_result($result);
```

Hope this helps.